# What could cmake work but ccmake fails to build my project?

Tags: cmake, googletest

I have a project that builds with `cmake ..`, but with `ccmake ..` (default, `c`, `c`, `g`) it skips the `gtest_main` which is kind of crucial.

What could be the difference? Any ideas to debug this build?

**Edit:** This is the biggest difference after a running both commands:

```
$ tree build/googletest build_ccmake/googletest 
build/googletest
├── CMakeFiles
│   ├── CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake
│   └── progress.marks
├── cmake_install.cmake
├── CTestTestfile.cmake
├── googlemock
│   ├── CMakeFiles
│   │   ├── CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake
│   │   ├── gmock.dir
│   │   │   ├── __
│   │   │   │   └── googletest
│   │   │   │       └── src
│   │   │   ├── build.make
│   │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │   │   ├── cmake_clean_target.cmake
│   │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │   │   ├── depend.make
│   │   │   ├── flags.make
│   │   │   ├── link.txt
│   │   │   ├── progress.make
│   │   │   └── src
│   │   ├── gmock_main.dir
│   │   │   ├── __
│   │   │   │   └── googletest
│   │   │   │       └── src
│   │   │   ├── build.make
│   │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │   │   ├── cmake_clean_target.cmake
│   │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │   │   ├── depend.make
│   │   │   ├── flags.make
│   │   │   ├── link.txt
│   │   │   ├── progress.make
│   │   │   └── src
│   │   └── progress.marks
│   ├── cmake_install.cmake
│   ├── CTestTestfile.cmake
│   ├── gtest
│   │   ├── CMakeFiles
│   │   │   ├── CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake
│   │   │   ├── gtest.dir
│   │   │   │   ├── build.make
│   │   │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │   │   │   ├── cmake_clean_target.cmake
│   │   │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │   │   │   ├── depend.make
│   │   │   │   ├── flags.make
│   │   │   │   ├── link.txt
│   │   │   │   ├── progress.make
│   │   │   │   └── src
│   │   │   ├── gtest_main.dir
│   │   │   │   ├── build.make
│   │   │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │   │   │   ├── cmake_clean_target.cmake
│   │   │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │   │   │   ├── depend.make
│   │   │   │   ├── flags.make
│   │   │   │   ├── link.txt
│   │   │   │   ├── progress.make
│   │   │   │   └── src
│   │   │   └── progress.marks
│   │   ├── cmake_install.cmake
│   │   ├── CTestTestfile.cmake
│   │   └── Makefile
│   └── Makefile
└── Makefile
build_ccmake/googletest
├── CMakeFiles
└── googlemock
    ├── CMakeFiles
    └── gtest
        └── CMakeFiles

24 directories, 47 files
```

Comment: Skips in what sense?

Comment: It generates an nearly empty subdirectory for googletest, I updated the question with more detail